# Rails / Token Input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've followed Ryan Bate's Railscast on Token Input and it works perfectly at my 'release' level using :

```
 <%= f.text_field :artist_tokens, "data-pre" => @release.artists.map(&:attributes).to_json, :class => "text" %
```

Under releases I have 'tracks' and want to be able to amend and alter the artists at the track level. Using the above I can make it 'inherit' the release level artists and this seems to work fine for the new method and initial set up, but on edit it obviously pulls back in the release level artists and if submit it hit, then all track level artists are overwritten.

I'm trying to do this:

```
<% if params[:action] == "edit" %>
<%= f.text_field :artist_tokens, "data-pre" => @track.artists.map(&:attributes).to_json, :class => "text" %>
<% else %>
<%= f.text_field :artist_tokens, "data-pre" => @release.artists.map(&:attributes).to_json, :class => "track_artist_tokens" %>
<% end %>
```

But I am getting getting an **Undefined Method 'artists' on @track.artists.map**

My models are as follows:

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_releases
  has_many :artists, :through => :artist_releases

  attr_reader :artist_tokens

    def artist_tokens=(ids)
      self.artist_ids = ids.split(",")
    end

  has_many :releases_tracks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tracks, :through => :releases_tracks

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => :true

  has_many :artists_tracks

end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_releases
  has_many :releases, :through => :artist_releases  
  has_many :artists_tracks
  has_many :tracks, :through => :artists_tracks
end



   class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :releases_tracks, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :releases, :through => :releases_tracks

      has_many :artists_tracks
      has_many :artists, :through => :artists_tracks

      attr_reader :artist_tokens
      def artist_tokens=(ids)
        self.artist_ids = ids.split(",")
      end

    end

class ArtistsTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :release
  belongs_to :track
end

class ReleasesTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :release
  belongs_to :track
  acts_as_list
end
```

Can anyone help?

UPDATES:

release controller tracks method:

```
def tracks
     @release = Release.find(params[:id])
     @track = @release.tracks.find(:all)
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html # tracks.html.erb
        end
  end
```

tracks.html.erb has:

```
    <%= form_for @release do |f| %>
            <%= f.fields_for :tracks do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'track_fields', :f => builder %>
            <% end %>
<% end %>
```

_track_fields.html.erb partial (with some of the HTML stripped for clarity)

```
<td class="label">Title:</td>
<td class="field"><%= f.text_field :name, :class => "text" %></td>

<td class="label">Artists:</td>
<td class="field">
    <% @track.each do |track| %>
    <%= f.text_field :artist_tokens, "data-pre" => track.artists.map(&:attributes).to_json, :class => "track_artist_tokens" %>
    <% end %>

<p><%= link_to 'Add new artist', new_artist_path, :remote => true %></p>

<td class="label">Version:</td>
<td class="field"><%= f.text_field :version, :class => "text" %></td>

<td class="label">ISRC:</td>
<td class="field"><%= f.text_field :isrc, :class => "text" %></td>

<td class="label">Remove:</td>
<td class="field"><%= f.check_box :_destroy %></td>
```

Comment: Where do you define `@track`? What is the complete error message?

Comment: I've  @track = @release.tracks.find(:all) defined in my release controller under the customer action 'track' (which I plan to loose and move this under new/edit eventually). The complete error, well first line is: NoMethodError in Releases#tracks

Comment: Mischa, I did have @track defined see above. Weirdly, in my show version of this, track.artists.map works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your `show` action `@track` is one `track` object. In the `customer` action it is a collection of `track` objects. So either you have to loop through them:

```
<% @track.each do |track| %>
  <%= f.text_field :artist_tokens, "data-pre" => track.artists.map(&:attributes).to_json, :class => "text" %>
<% end %>
```

Or get the first `track` of the collection:

```
<%= f.text_field :artist_tokens, "data-pre" => @track.first.artists.map(&:attributes).to_json, :class => "text" %>
```

Comment: Thanks Mischa, it's getting closer but still not quite there as I should have pointed out that this is within a look already, see my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387559/weird-looping-behaviour-whats-happening-here

Comment: I don't know how the code in your other question relates to the code in this question. Please update this one with the loop that you already have.

Comment: Thank you. So, in the code you just added, on what line does the error occur? And what error do get exactly?

Comment: Well, I added your first suggestion <% @track.each do |track| %> and there is now no error, just duplicated results for each track, so if I have two tracks, I get the artist input field twice and so on (see https://plus.google.com/photos/107187566563986410130/albums/5737535349357852897?authkey=CJT5xZz8zruAmwE). Your track.first.artists.map just gives me the first track's artists for every track.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, it was not clear to me that you didn't have an error anymore. I suggest we continue in your new question then.

Comment: This question is the current one, the other has slightly different methods/actions.... Thanks so much for your help so far!!

Comment: As you can see, it gets confusing if you try to get answers to different questions in one topic. The issue of the original error was solved, so please open a new question and describe the problem as accurately as possible. That way someone else may be able to help too. I don't think any other SO user has a clue what you need when they see this question.